# select multiple data in database mysql in asp.net mvc controller

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem pertaining to selecting data from a database and I don't really know why. If I add this sheet.Add(sheetModel); to my other query it gives 
invisible data to my table row.

I have here the first select data query:

```
        // START of IN AND OUT NOT POSTING
        String configuration = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ToString();
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(configuration);
        String query = @"SELECT effectiveDate,

      MAX(CASE
         WHEN note = 'REGULAR LOGGED' and description = description and timestatus='OK' and counter ='1'
        THEN concat(description,' ',log)
        WHEN  description = description
        THEN description
        WHEN note = 'REGULAR LOGGED' and  DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Saturday' and timestatus='OK' and counter ='1'  then CONCAT('Saturday',' ',log)
        WHEN DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Sunday' and note = 'REGULAR LOGGED'  and timestatus='OK' and counter ='1'  then CONCAT('Sunday',' ',log)
        WHEN note = 'REGULAR LOGGED' and counter ='1' and timestatus='OK'
        THEN log
        WHEN note = 'VACATION LEAVE' and timestatus='OK' and counter ='1'
        THEN 'VACATION LEAVE'
        WHEN note = 'SICK LEAVE' and timestatus='OK' and counter ='1'
        THEN 'SICK LEAVE'
        WHEN note is not null and counter ='1' and DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Sunday' and timestatus='OK'
        THEN CONCAT('Sunday',' ',note)
        WHEN note is not null and counter ='1' and DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Saturday' and timestatus='OK'
        THEN CONCAT('Saturday',' ',note)
        WHEN DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Saturday'
        THEN 'Saturday'
        WHEN DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Sunday'
        THEN 'Sunday'
        WHEN note is not null and counter ='1' and timestatus='OK'
        THEN note

      END) am1,

      MAX(CASE
         WHEN note = 'REGULAR LOGGED' and description = description and timestatus='OK' and counter ='2'
        THEN concat(description,' ',log)
        WHEN  description = description
        THEN description
        WHEN note = 'REGULAR LOGGED' and  DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Saturday' and timestatus='OK' and counter ='2'  then CONCAT('Saturday',' ',log)
        WHEN DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Sunday' and note = 'REGULAR LOGGED'  and timestatus='OK' and counter ='2'  then CONCAT('Sunday',' ',log)
        WHEN note = 'REGULAR LOGGED' and counter ='2' and timestatus='OK'
        THEN log
        WHEN note = 'VACATION LEAVE' and timestatus='OK' and counter ='2'
        THEN 'VACATION LEAVE'
        WHEN note = 'SICK LEAVE' and timestatus='OK' and counter ='2'
        THEN 'SICK LEAVE'
        WHEN note is not null and counter ='2' and DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Sunday' and timestatus='OK'
        THEN CONCAT('Sunday',' ',note)
        WHEN note is not null and counter ='2' and DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Saturday' and timestatus='OK'
        THEN CONCAT('Saturday',' ',note)
        WHEN DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Saturday'
        THEN 'Saturday'
        WHEN DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Sunday'
        THEN 'Sunday'
        WHEN note is not null and counter ='2' and timestatus='OK'
        THEN note

      END) am2,

      MAX(CASE
         WHEN note = 'REGULAR LOGGED' and description = description and timestatus='OK' and counter ='3'
        THEN concat(description,' ',log)
        WHEN  description = description
        THEN description
        WHEN note = 'REGULAR LOGGED' and  DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Saturday' and timestatus='OK' and counter ='3'  then CONCAT('Saturday',' ',log)
        WHEN DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Sunday' and note = 'REGULAR LOGGED'  and timestatus='OK' and counter ='3'  then CONCAT('Sunday',' ',log)
        WHEN note = 'REGULAR LOGGED' and counter ='3' and timestatus='OK'
        THEN log
        WHEN note = 'VACATION LEAVE' and timestatus='OK' and counter ='3'
        THEN 'VACATION LEAVE'
        WHEN note = 'SICK LEAVE' and timestatus='OK' and counter ='3'
        THEN 'SICK LEAVE'
            WHEN note is not null and counter ='3' and DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Sunday' and timestatus='OK'
        THEN CONCAT('Sunday',' ',note)
        WHEN note is not null and counter ='3' and DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Saturday' and timestatus='OK'
        THEN CONCAT('Saturday',' ',note)
        WHEN DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Saturday'
        THEN 'Saturday'
        WHEN DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Sunday'
        THEN 'Sunday'
        WHEN note is not null and counter ='3' and timestatus='OK'
        THEN note

      END) am3,

      MAX(CASE
         WHEN note = 'REGULAR LOGGED' and description = description and timestatus='OK' and counter ='4'
        THEN concat(description,' ',log)
        WHEN  description = description
        THEN description
        WHEN note = 'REGULAR LOGGED' and  DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Saturday' and timestatus='OK' and counter ='4'  then CONCAT('Saturday',' ',log)
        WHEN DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Sunday' and note = 'REGULAR LOGGED'  and timestatus='OK' and counter ='4'  then CONCAT('Sunday',' ',log)
        WHEN note = 'REGULAR LOGGED' and counter ='4' and timestatus='OK'
        THEN log
        WHEN note = 'VACATION LEAVE' and timestatus='OK' and counter ='4'
        THEN 'VACATION LEAVE'
        WHEN note = 'SICK LEAVE' and timestatus='OK' and counter ='4'
        THEN 'SICK LEAVE'
            WHEN note is not null and counter ='4' and DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Sunday' and timestatus='OK'
        THEN CONCAT('Sunday',' ',note)
        WHEN note is not null and counter ='4' and DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Saturday' and timestatus='OK'
        THEN CONCAT('Saturday',' ',note)
        WHEN DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Saturday'
        THEN 'Saturday'
        WHEN DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Sunday'
        THEN 'Sunday'
        WHEN note is not null and counter ='4' and timestatus='OK'
        THEN note

      END) am4,

    DATE_FORMAT(effectiveDate, '%W') as DAY_OF_WEEK

    FROM schedules
    LEFT JOIN timesheet ON schedules.effectiveDate = timesheet.date and schedules.empid = timesheet.empid
    LEFT JOIN holidays ON schedules.effectiveDate = holidays.date
    WHERE effectiveDate <= CURDATE()
    AND YEAR(effectiveDate) = YEAR(CURDATE())
    AND MONTH(effectiveDate) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND schedules.empid = '16'
    GROUP BY effectiveDate";

        connection.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            var sheetModel = new combine();
            sheetModel.sheet = new timesheet();
            sheetModel.user = new User();

            sheetModel.sheet.in_log_am = dr["am1"].ToString();
            sheetModel.sheet.out_log_am = dr["am2"].ToString();
            sheetModel.sheet.in_log_pm = dr["am3"].ToString();
            sheetModel.sheet.out_log_pm = dr["am4"].ToString();
            sheetModel.sheet.day_today = dr["DAY_OF_WEEK"].ToString();
            sheetModel.sheet.dated = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["effectiveDate"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            sheet.Add(sheetModel);
        }
        connection.Close();
```

Gives me the result of:

[image: This is result]

But I want to select using a second query:

```
String sql9 = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y') as YEAR FROM timesheet WHERE empid='16' GROUP BY YEAR";
                MySqlCommand cmd9 = new MySqlCommand(sql9, connection);
                connection.Open();
                MySqlDataReader dr9 = cmd9.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr9.Read())
                {
                    var fetch_absences = new combine();
                    fetch_absences.sheet = new timesheet();
                    fetch_absences.user = new User();
                    fetch_absences.user.sl = dr9["YEAR"].ToString();
                    sheet.Add(fetch_absences);                        
                }

                connection.Close();
```

If add that query to my controller the result of my first image will now be this one:

[image]

Comment: What you want to achieve: removing 2 empty rows below or adding new rows below existing results? Consider using stored procedures & test your second query in MySQL to see why it returns 2 empty rows.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto yes tetsuya.. i have 2empty rows below.. my query is correct.. if add another select query in same model. i got that 2 empty rows

Comment: What `sheet` instance belongs to (provide what library you've used in view to display query results, I think you're using third party one)? Even I don't know what object that `combine` & `timesheet` methods declared for.

Comment: I used 2 class 1. is timesheet and 2. User class. so I created combine class to combine that 2 class.. so i have         public timesheet sheet { get; set; }
        public User user { get; set; }

Comment: so in my controller i declared List<combine> sheet = new List<combine>();

Comment: as you can see i declared this sheet.Add(fetch_absences); to my 2 both different query.. i dont know why is not working if add other query..

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto in short to my question how to apply 2 model in one return..